# Select dynamic ngFor item property set into @input decorator

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components

On my Angular 6 code, i try to create my select component.

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="selecteditemid">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
       {{item.inputfield}} <---- ERRORE
   </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

On @Input() I have inputfield , e Key of items property...How do you do to create item.myinputfield?

my items 1:
    [{
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Kevin",
    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Jordan"
    }
    ]

my items 2:
    [{
       "id": 1,
       "hobby": "Read Book",
    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "hobby": "Music"
    }
    ]

On first case i want to display name property on i set the input with name; on second case i would to set input with hobby property of json data. My @Input() is the property on items. See above code when display inputfield the item is blank.

Thank's in advanced for help!. Marco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [] like this

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="selecteditemid">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
       {{item[inputfield]}}
   </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```